# Referencing metatable Created in C from Lua 5.1.5

Tags: lua

In my C I create a global metatable:

```
luaL_newmetatable(L, "WebSocketClient");
lua_pushliteral(L, "close");
lua_pushcfunction(L, lws_sock_close);
lua_rawset(L, -3);
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

But in my Lua I cannot add a function to it:

```
function WebSocketClient:read_frame()
   --foo
end
```

I get this error:

```
attempt to index local 'WebSocketClient' (a nil value)
```

How do I make this metatable available to my Lua code so I can add more functions to it?

Comment: In Lua metatables are handled differently. You usually want to create a normal table with functions, then pass it to `setmetatable` function, which should convert it. Look [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetamethodsTutorial). WRT `luaL_newmetatable`, [this short doc](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/luaL_newmetatable) might help.

Comment: I typed the version from memory, but I was wrong, I'm using 5.1.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on Bartek's comment (which is correct, though brief): If you want to add new functions to a metatable from Lua, you need to expose that table to Lua. luaL_newmetatable stores your WebSocketClient metatable in the [Registry](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.5), which is only accessible through C (outside of [debug.getregistry](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-debug.getregistry) in the debug API, which may be removed when sandboxing Lua code).

You're better off creating a normal table, exporting it via your C library's table, and then using [luaL_setmetatable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_setmetatable) (from C) or setmetatable (from Lua) -- think of the registry as a place to put values internal to C modules.

The way you're using luaL_newmetatable defines a metatable that explicitly should not be accessible from Lua for security reasons, so that e.g. Lua script end-users can't mess with a core type's metatable. Useful in other cases, but not what you want here.

Comment: I was kind of busy back then, and I didn't want to post such an incomplete hint as an answer, so I've decided to post a comment. `+1`, nicely put.

Answer (score 2):

Providing code based on @silentbicycle’s answer:

```
lua_newtable(L);
lua_pushliteral(L, "close");
lua_pushcfunction(L, lws_sock_close);
lua_rawset(L, -3);
lua_setglobal(L, "WebSocketClient");
```

And for reference you set the metatable like so:

```
lua_newtable(L);
lua_newtable(L);
lua_pushliteral(L, "__index");
lua_getglobal(L, "WebSocketClient");
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
lua_settable(L, -3);
```

Comment: Use `lua_setglobal` instead of `lua_setfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX` and `lua_getglobal` instead of `lua_getfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX`.

Comment: @lhf these are just macros, no? Aha! `#define lua_setglobal(L,s) lua_setfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, (s))`, `getglobal` is analoguous.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, yes they are macros in 5.1 but functions in 5.2. Using them makes the code work in both versions.